# Compare texts within a table in python

Tags: python, string, nlp, compare, nltk

I want to compare text in a python list with each other .
For example

```
Url         | text
            |
www.xyz.com | " hello bha njik **bhavd bhavd** bjavd manhbd kdkndsik wkjdk"
            | 
www.abc.com | "bhavye jsbsdv sjbs jcsbjd adjbsd jdfhjdb jdshbjf jdsbjf"
            |
www.lokj.com| "bsjgad adhuad jadshjasd kdashda kdajikd kdfsj **bhavd bhavd** "
```

Now I want to compare 1st text with  other rows   so as to know how many words are similar in the texts.
and progressively second row with the following rows and so on ....

What should be the approach i use and what data structure shall I use ?

Comment: Do you want to compare only with the following values? Like a with 2 but not 2 with 1 since you have the value already? (So the first half of the similarity matrix)

Answer (score 2):

*For python3*

As detailed in the comments, we generate each possible pair, create sets to assure words uniqueness and we count simply count the number of unique common words for each pair. This may need to be adapted a bit if your text list structure is a bit different

```
import itertools

my_list = ["a text a", "an other text b", "a last text c and so on"]

def simil(text_a, text_b):
    # returns the number of common unique words betwene two texts 
    return len(set(text_a.split()).intersection(set(text_b.split())))

results = []
# for each unique combination of texts
for pair in itertools.combinations(my_list, r=2):
    results.append(simil(*pair))

print(result)
```

Side note: depending on what you want to do, you may want to look at algorithms such as **TFIDF** ([A simple tutorial](http://stevenloria.com/finding-important-words-in-a-document-using-tf-idf/)) for texts/documents similarity, or many others...

Answer (score 0):

Best way you can use `OrderedDict()`, which useful to maintain the order to fetch out the `dict keys`.

By iterating on that dict, comparing values you will get your output

Answer (score 0):

A possible way could be converting each string to a set of words and afterwards compare the intersection of the sets

```
string_1 = "hello bha njik bhavd bhavd bjavd manhbd kdkndsik wkjdk"
string_2 = "bhavd dskghfski fjfbhskf ewkjhsdkifs fjuekdjsdf ue"

# First split your strings into sets of words
set_1 = set(string_1.split())
set_2 = set(string_2.split())

# Compare the sets to find where they both have the same value
print set_1 & set_2
print set_1.intersection(set_2)

# Both print out {'bhavd'}
```